# Javascript value takings

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have javascript and I want to take information from selection **data-id=""** but not from **value=""**.

If I changed this: `multiplier = $(this).val();` to `multiplier = this.attr("data-id");` my script does not work.

Any solutions?
This does work

```js
            jQuery(function() {
                var multiplier = 1;

                // bind keyup
                 $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
                   var value = this.value;
                   var valuemath = value / multiplier;  
                    $("#dom_element").val(valuemath);   
                });

                $('#dePlooi').change(function(){
                    multiplier = $(this).val();
                    $("#txt_name").trigger("keyup");
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  value="" placeholder="Enter your KW"/>
                
<select id="dePlooi">
  <option data-id="1" value="1">KW</option>
  <option data-id="1.34102209" value="1.34102209">HP</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input id="dom_element" value="" disabled/>KW
```

This does not work

```js
jQuery(function() {
                var multiplier = 1;

                // bind keyup
                 $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
                   var value = this.value;
                   var valuemath = value / multiplier;  
                    $("#dom_element").val(valuemath);   
                });

                $('#dePlooi').change(function(){
                    multiplier = this.attr("data-id");
                    $("#txt_name").trigger("keyup");
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  value="" placeholder="Enter your KW"/>
                
<select id="dePlooi">
  <option data-id="1" value="1">KW</option>
  <option data-id="1.34102209" value="1.34102209">HP</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input id="dom_element" value="" disabled/>KW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to get the data attribute value:

```
$(this).find(':selected').data('id');
```

Comment: Hi,
No, also this does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/2m519s7n/1/

Comment: Updated, can you please try this

Answer (score 1):

You need this

```
multiplier = $(':selected', this).data("id");
```

It's because the `this` is the `select` element and not the `option` element which you want the `data-id` attribute from. You first need to find the selected `option` before you can fetch the `data-id` aatribute. The `.val()` method from jQuery does this automatically, but not the `.attr()` method (which it shouldn't)

```js
jQuery(function() {
                var multiplier = 1;

                // bind keyup
                 $("#txt_name").on("keyup change", function() {
                   var value = this.value;
                   var valuemath = value / multiplier;  
                    $("#dom_element").val(valuemath);   
                });

                $('#dePlooi').change(function(){
                    multiplier = $(':selected', this).data("id");
                    $("#txt_name").trigger("keyup");
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt_name"  value="" placeholder="Enter your KW"/>
                
<select id="dePlooi">
  <option data-id="1" value="1">KW</option>
  <option data-id="1.34102209" value="1.34102209">HP</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input id="dom_element" value="" disabled/>KW
```